# Problema al mostrar digitos de captcha php

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema al momento de visualizar los digitos generados por un archivo captcha que realize

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ven muy pequeños los digitos

este es el codigo del archivo

```
$ranStr = md5(microtime());

$ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $ranStr;

$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("c.jpg");

$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);

imagestring($newImage, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

imagejpeg($newImage);
?>
```

Comment: y si haces la imagen del tamaño de los digitos y a la imagen la haces mas grande???

Comment: le hice mas grande pero me siguen apareciendo los numeros pequeños

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo html y css donde insertas la imagen???

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en el uso del `header` y la funcion `imagejpeg`:

estoy asumiendo que tiras la imagen al navegador y la estas capturado mediante `AJAX`...

cosa que estaría bien siempre y cuando al pintarla en el lugar que deseas comprendas que debes controlar las dimensiones yo implementaría algo así:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$color_texto = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $color_texto);
ob_start();
imagejpeg( $im, NULL, 100 );
imagedestroy( $im );
$i = ob_get_clean();
echo '<img style="height:50px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $i ).'">';
```

En este Caso yo hago lo mismo; con la diferencia que Capturo la creación de la imagen en buffer y la transformo en una imagen en base64.

Esto me da el control de Manipular el tamaño de imagen imagino que pueden haber otros métodos.